# Out of home folder .pyc files?

Tags: python, linux

If I place my project in /usr/bin/

will my python interpreter generate bytecode?  If so where does it put them as the files do not have write permission in that folder.  Does it cache them in a temp file?

If not, is there a performance loss for me putting the project there?

I have packaged this up as a .deb file that is installed from my Ubuntu ppa, so the obvious place to install the project is in /usr/bin/

but if I don't generate byte code by putting it there what should I do?  Can I give the project write permission if it installs on another persons machine?  that would seem to be a security risk.

There are surely lots of python projects installed in Ubuntu ( and obviously other distros ) how do they deal with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the script in `/usr/bin`, if you execute your script as a user that doesn't have permissions to write in `/usr/bin`, then the `.pyc` files won't be created and, as far as I know, there isn't any other caching mechanism.

This means that your file will be byte compiled by the interpreter every time so, yes, there will be a performance loss. However, probably that loss it's not noticeable. Note that when a source file is updated, the compiled file is updated automatically without the user noticing it (at least most of the times).

What I've seen is the common practice in Ubuntu is to use small scripts in `/usr/bin` without even the `.py` extension. Those scripts are byte compiled very fast, so you don't need to worry about that. They just import a library and call some kind of `library.main.Application().run()` method and that's all.

Note that the library is installed in a different path and that all library files are byte compiled for different python versions. If that's not the case in your package, then you have to review you `setup.py` and your `debian` files since that's not the way it should be.

Comment: Thanks very much.  So I think the answer should be to compile on my machine and distribute the .pyc files in the .deb file.

Comment: @Caustic No, you distribute your source files and the packaging scripts take care of compiling them when they are installed for every available python installation. Please have a look at the [packaging guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python).

Comment: *facepalm*  yes of course.  Thanks heaps!  That makes most sense.

Answer (score 1):

.pyc/.pyo files are not generated for scripts that are run directly. Python modules placed where Python modules are normally expected and packaged up have the .pyc/.pyo files generated at either build time or install time, and so aren't the end user's problem.